# short div tag from html why loop in react

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am new to react JS platform. but decided to try to hands-on that I have stuck at one simple thing.

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
```

I have set this HTML get from my database, now I need to make a loop so I can convert this string to an array structure for every div. anyone has an idea how can I able to do that. below is my code not working properly.

```
$(sliderContent).each(function() {
                    tempArray.push(
                        <div className={classes.slides}>
                            {this}
                        </div>
                    );
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you store wrong values in your DB, you just need to keep vaues in your DB not div tags, just store string values in your Array/Object and you can run each loop to display in DOM, for learning React you need to learn by it's approach do not compare React with jquery, it will raise your confusion.

```
DBData =['val1','val2','val3']
```

react code

```
DBData.each((_e,_i)=>{
 return <div key={_i}> _e </div>
})
```

react is not similar as jquery.

Comment: I am working on the PWA frontend on magento 2, where I have already static block stored in a database that has the above value now, I need to convert it into slider in react Js that's why it's stored there this way. i can not change that block value, I need to manage HTML i js

Comment: @Yogesh for this you don't need to store DOM element in database because when you iterate it react will behave with them as text not like DOM element. Just store string values only in DB and run each loop as give you react code.

Comment: thank you but that's not possible. same block call on web also, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Used simple logic, take a reference of the above div, and use each loop. It's not proper solution but works fine

```
let tempArray = [];
    
$('.homepage-brand-slider div').each(function() {
     tempArray.push(this);
});
```